# Can Change UserAgent=SIPAUA/0.1.001 android.net.sip native android studio?

Tags: java, android, user-agent

I need to change the default user agent in the android.net.sip library for android sip calls

trafic packages red:

`User-Agent="SIPAUA/0.1.001"` this moment

I can't find a method in the library where I can modify this "UserAgent" variable, currently the packet traffic gives me the following value of the variable:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
REGISTER sip:ip-pb.phone.net SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 6459390033e486c95e9e255b4a9ee073@10.1.10.1
CSeq: 4883 REGISTER
From: <sip:130001111@ip-pbx10.phone.net>;tag=25224523
To: <sip:130001111@ip-pbx10.phone.net>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.10.1:56751;branch=z9hG4bK980ea033c043c399f0368195e8fe5704363534;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: SIPAUA/0.1.001
Contact: *
Expires: 0
Content-Length: 0
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using android studio and its respective library for sip calls.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary

Comment: What prevents you from doing so?

Comment: there is no method to overwrite this variable